# json_encode certain elements of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array $people which looks like:

```
Array
    (
[0] => Array
       (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => John
        [address] => 
        [city] => 
        [postcode] => 
        [updated_at] => 2015-06-01 13:18:32
        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => Paul
        [address => 
        [city] => 
        [postcode] => 
        [updated_at] => 2015-06-26 10:59:58
        [created_at] => 2015-06-01 13:20:30
    )
 )
```

I want to generate some JSON from this data but it will only contain the id and name for each one. For example:

```
    [
         {
             "name-ref": "john",
             "identifier": "2"
         },
         {
             "name-ref": "Paul",
             "identifier": "4"
         }
    ]
```

Notice the names for them are different as well. How may i go about this?

Thankyou

Comment: first create a array which you want then json_encode it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work. Try it out and show me the response if its not the one that you desire.

```
    $outputArray = array();
foreach ($givenArray as $key => $value) {
    # code...
    $outputArray[$key]['name-ref'] = $value['name']
    $outputArray[$key]['identifier'] =  $value['id']
}

echo json_encode(array_values($outputArray));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$final_array = array();
$count = 0;

foreach ($people as $p){
   $final_array[$count]['id'] = $p['id'];
   $final_array[$count]['name'] = $p['name'];
   $count++;
}

echo json_encode ($final_array);

?>
```